# Split String in the Middle

Tags: r, string

I have a list of strings like

```
1   Aken Jan van Jan van Aken
2   Albani Stephan Stephan Albani
```

and I want to split it exactly in the middle so I can keep the latter part.

Is there a better option than looping this ?

```
library(qdap)
test <- "Aken van Jan Jan van Aken"
paste0(strsplit(test," ")[[1]][((word_count(test)/2)+1):word_count(test)], collapse=' ')
```

Comment: Sorry, it is in qdap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering `dput(df)` as :

```
structure(list(s1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Aken Jan van Jan van Aken", 
"Albani Stephan Stephan Albani"), 
class = "factor")), .Names = "s1", 
row.names= c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

you can try this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(half_string=
   substr(s1, nchar(as.character(s1))/2, nchar(as.character(s1)))) %>%
  select(half_string)
```

or using the `stringr` package:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(half_string = str_sub(s1, start=nchar(as.character(s1))/2)) %>%
  select(half_string)
```

Note: `nchar(as.character(s1))/2` takes the roof values in case of decimals, if you want to use ceiling values, try `nchar(as.character(s1))/2 + 0.5` instead

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to get the first name.

```
test <- "Aken van Jan Jan van Aken"
test1 <- "Albani Stephan Stephan Albani"
l=list(test, test1)
i=lapply(l, function(x) substr(x, start = 1, stop = ceiling(nchar(x)/2)))
j=lapply(l, function(x) substr(x, start = ceiling(nchar(x)/2), stop = nchar(x) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to split in the "middle" ie for every 6 words, get the last 3...which I don't think is a very consistent parsing mechanism but I don't know the entire data  set obviously this should work with package:stringi

```
f.split <- function(str){
        as.character(
            stri_extract_all_regex(
                str,
                sprintf('((\\w+) ?){%s}$',
                        stri_count_words(str)/2),
                simplify = T)
            )
    }
```

It's also vectorized, so iteration isn't an issue:

```
f.split(c("Aken Jan van Jan van Aken","Albani Stephan Stephan Albani"))
[1] "Jan van Aken"   "Stephan Albani"
```